# how to implement add to cart functionality on custom module

Tags: magento-1.7

I am new in magento. I have made a custom module of price calculator in which a user enter the height and width of a product and it gets its price.
I want to implement add to cart functionality so that height,width and price goes to cart. But i don't know the code and syntax to implement it.

Cart functionality is already installed on my project.

This is controller

```
class Test_Mymodule_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action 
{
    public function indexAction() 
    { 
         $this->loadLayout(); 
         $this->renderLayout(); 
    }

    public function calculateAction()
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $printdata = $request->getPost();

        if($this->getRequest()->isPost()) 
         {
             $obj = Mage::getModel("test_mymodule/results");

             $show_results = $obj->showshuttersprice($printdata['width'],$printdata['height']);

         }



         Mage::register('data', $show_results);// In the Controller

         Mage::register('width', $printdata['width']);// In the Controller

         Mage::register('height', $printdata['height']);// In the Controller


            $this->loadLayout();
            $this->renderLayout();           

    } 
}
```

This is my view in which i want to implement add to cart

```
<?php 
 $data = Mage::registry('data');// In the View;

 $width = Mage::registry('width');// In the View;   

 $height = Mage::registry('height');// In the View;     

if($data == "0" || $data == "NULL" || $data == "")
{
    echo "Sorry, Product is Unavailable";
}
else
{ 
?>

<h6 align="center">Price Results for <?php echo $width; ?> mm by <?php echo $height; ?> mm Domestic Rollershutter</h6>
     <table border="1" align="center" width="100%" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="4">
           <tr>
               <td>Price</td> <td><?php echo "$"." ".$data; ?></td>
           </tr>

       </table>      



<?php
}
?>
<br />
<a href ="">Add to cart</a>
```

Any body help me...

Answer (score 1):

There are two options.

## Adding via Query string

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/catalog/adding_a_product_to_the_cart_via_querystring

```
/path/to/magento/checkout/cart/add?product=$id&qty=$qty&options[$id]=$value
```

## Adding via code

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698236/add-product-to-cart-with-custom-options